# Application Insights Duplicated - phantom targets

Tags: c#, azure-application-insights

My code calls a target by its DNS `api.target-service.com` but when I look at the application insights dependencies, I actually see 2 targets: `api.target-service.com` (which is expected) and `api.target-service.com | cid-v1:3ac2da73-ba6d-4ebf-8f90-2c04ba50d10c`

This happens not only for http dependencies but also MS SQL database ones...

How can I prevent this? am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you by any chance both added the ai sdk to your code *and* enabled AI on the web app?

Comment: no... its a container/AKS deployed app... no web app...